# Why current = current->next gives segmentation fault when current->next == NULL?

Tags: c, debugging, null, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have below C program to implement an ascending order linked-list. Problem is in buildList() function so you can ignore other function apart from main() and buildList().

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void buildList(struct node **, int);
void printList(struct node **);

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head = NULL; /*Empty list*/

    int hold, i, j;
    printf("How many integers in this list: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    j = 1;
    for(i; i > 0; i--)
    {
            printf("Integer %d: ",j);
            scanf("%d",&hold);
            buildList(&head, hold);
            j++;
    }
    printList(&head);
    return 0;
}

void buildList(struct node **headRef, int data)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current, *current1;
    current = *headRef;
    //If list is empty, add the number as the first node.
    if (current == NULL)
    {
            newNode->data = data;
            newNode->next = *headRef;
            *headRef = newNode;
    }
   //If the list is not empty.
    else
    {
            //If the number is not greater than first number.
            if (data <= current->data)
            {
                    newNode->data = data;
                    newNode->next = current;
                    *headRef = newNode;
            }
            //If the number is greater than the first number in list.
            else
            {
                    int flag = 0;
                    while (data > (current->data))
                    {
                            current1 = current;
                            current = current->next;
                    }


                    newNode->data = data;
                    current1->next = newNode;
                    newNode->next = current;
            }
    }
}

//Prints nodes and total number of nodes.
void printList(struct node **headRef)
{
    int count = 0;
    struct node *current;
    current = *headRef;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
            count++;
            printf("%d ",current->data);
            current = current->next;

    }
    printf("\nTotal nodes: %d\n",count);
}
```

This program works fine untill I give a number which is bigger than any number present in the list. In that case I get a segmentation fault.

Case I (Fine correct output)

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
How many integers in this list: 3
Integer 1: 5
Integer 2: 1
Integer 3: 4
1 4 5
Total nodes: 3
-bash-4.1$
```

Case II (Here code breaks(segmentation fault))

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
How many integers in this list: 3
Integer 1: 5
Integer 2: 6
Segmentation fault
-bash-4.1$
```

After a long time trying to figure out what was going wrong in my code, I figured out that when a number was bigger then any number in the list, in which case it was to be inserted at the end of the list, this statement (in the last else in function buildList()) was causing the issue:

```
  current = current->next;
```

I finally figured out that when current->next is NULL, this statement cause seg fault.

I came up with a workaround like below and it worked giving correct output.

```
 else
 {
     int flag = 0;
     while (data > (current->data))
     {
         current1 = current;
         if(current->next != NULL)
         {
             current = current->next;
         }
         else
         {
             flag = 1;
             break;
         }
    }
    newNode->data = data;
    current1->next = newNode;
    if (flag == 1)
    {
       newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
       newNode->next = current;
    }
}
```

Now I get correct output.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
How many integers in this list: 3
Integer 1: 5
Integer 2: 1
Integer 3: 10
1 5 10
Total nodes: 3
-bash-4.1$
```

Now I am left wondering why wasn't current = current->next; working when current->next was NULL. I was expecting this statement to assign NULL to current.

Could anyone please tell me the reason for this ?
Also was my workaround a good one ? Or is there a better way to do it?

Sorry for this long question, but spending like 2 hours debugging this, i guess I am going crazy.

Thanks.

Comment: @lurker Isn't that how you add nodes at the beginning of a linked list ? By overwriting the head of this list ? I learnt linked-list by going through a tutorial which I found online, and it said that is how you add nodes at the beginning of a linked-list. Please let me know if that is not a standard way.

Comment: Sorry, it's correct. I was not looking carefully at the `next` setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your debugging technique is giving you a bit of a red herring. The problem is in this loop:

```
while (data > (current->data))
{
    current1 = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

But not with the line you think it is. If `current->next` is `NULL`, `current` gets set to `NULL` just as you describe. The next operation that takes place, however is the loop condition - which dereferences `current`. Blammo.  You probably want something like:

```
while (current && (data > current->data))
{
    current1 = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

I didn't analyze your whole program, so I can't really comment on the correctness of this part of it other than the obvious crasher.

Comment: Damn !! How didnt I think about it !!! I guess I have to take a break, I have been like programming like crazy for past 3-4 days and my mind needs a break maybe . But thanks man. One good thing is that my understanding was correct that current would be NULL.

Comment: @user266168, you should probably learn to use a debugger. It can help you find bugs like this one in no time.

Comment: Yea, I read about how helpful a debugger can be on a page online. Does any debugger come inbuilt with CentOS Linux (like gcc compiler i mean) ? Because I ssh into my school lab centOS linux machine to practice C, and I dont think I will be allowed to install anything there by myself.

Answer (score 2):

This `while` loop will not stop when the second input is greater than the first input.

```
     while ( data > (current->data))
     {
        current1 = current;
        current = current->next;
     }
```

You end up dereferencing a NULL pointer. You need:

```
     while ( current != NULL && data > (current->data))
     {
        current1 = current;
        current = current->next;
     }
```

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks. Carl also pointed out same mistake I had made. I was just changing the code and testing when you wrote this answer. yes the root cause was i was dereferencing a NULL pointer.